# Retrofit not working with maps api of sha256 test url

Tags: android, google-maps, ssl, retrofit

I have used retrofit for google Places and direction API integration.Recently I got update from Google Maps for Work Support Team that In order to make sure your applications are not impacted you need to verify that the HTTPS client you are using supports SHA-256.

They have provided one test url(https://cert-test.sandbox.google.com) to validate that http-client is compatible or not

I have used https://cert-test.sandbox.google.com to validate with Retrofit but It is failing and giving me exception as mentioned below:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x1027ce0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error

To be clear, I have used plain okhttpclient with this integration.

please do needful if anybody have fix for it.

Comment: which okhttp library version you are using?

Comment: I am using okhttp:2.4.0

Comment: pls try to update it to 2.5.0 then check again

Comment: you can also refer https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1628

Comment: any specific reason for it?

Comment: I have faced many issues related to SSL in older version of okhttp that's why

Comment: I have tried 2.5.0 version okhttp and still same issue is occuring

Answer (score 0):

Looks that server is using `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` cipher. It only started being supported in API 20 (L Preview).  You can see a list of supported ciphers by API level on the [`SSLSocket` docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html).

Try running your test on a 5.0 or above device.  For example, the following code is successful on a device running 5.0, but gets an SSL exception on 4.4.4 --

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder().get().url("https://cert-test.sandbox.google.com/")
  .build();

response = client.newCall(request).execute();
Log.d(TAG, "code = " + response.code());
```

but the same is also true for the equivalent `URLConnection` code --

```
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL("https://cert-test.sandbox.google.com/").openConnection();
con.connect();
Log.d(TAG, "code = " + con.getResponseCode());
```

The issue is not retrofit or okhttp, but the limitations of the default security providers provided on older phones.

You can work around it by installing a new provider.  Google makes one available through google play services, and is easy to install.  One line (plus exception handling, etc).

```
try {
    ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
     // Fix it
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
     // Skip it
}
```

For a full example, see ["Updating Your Security Provider to Protect Against SSL Exploits"](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html) from Google.

Doing this will allow the above two code blocks to run on lower API versions if the phone has Google Play installed.